# Use of Angular ui-route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use ui-route to create 3 pages that share a single state for loading them by having state url parameters by dynamic and loading views/controllers based on those parameters. The challenge is this is what i have now but i feel i am not doing it right; can anyone point me in the right direction?

Javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui-router','positionControllers']);

myApp.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('list', {
      url: '/list',
      templateUrl: 'list.html',
      controller: 'ListController'
    })
    .state('list.detail', {
      url: '^/:id',
      views: {
        'detail': {
          templateUrl: 'detail.html',
          controller: 'DetailsController'
        }
      },
    })
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'partial-home.html'
    });
}
])
```

Comment: Your code example is using Angular's `ngRoute`, not `ui-router`. Which one do you mean to use?

Comment: @Phil ui-router is what i want to use

Comment: DId you even go through the basic ui-router tutorial before posting here. You might want to have a reading of this `https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki` to get the concepts

Answer (score 0):

Here an example using **ui-router**:

http://plnkr.co/edit/VALhQ3SCUGvYkSxZvy7j?p=preview

```
.config(['$stateProvider',
    function($stateProvider) {

      $stateProvider
        .state('list', {
          url: '/list',
          templateUrl: 'list.html',
          controller: 'ListCtrl'
        })
        .state('list.detail', {
          url: '^/:id',
          views: {
            'detail': {
              templateUrl: 'detail.html',
              controller: 'DetailCtrl'
            }
          },
        });
    }
  ])
```

Comment: look and the new change i made to the code. Why doesn't it still work?